# Should a number after a word in ALL_CAPS style be preceded by an underscore?

Tags: naming-conventions

I tried to find literature on this but couldn't seem to find any. Examples in PEP8 do not include digits (I'm using Python, but this question should be language agnostic).

In `snake_case`, I would write `variable1`, `variable2`, and this is fine to me as the number stand out.

However, in `ALL_CAPS`, I instinctively write `VARIABLE_1`, `VARIABLE_2` instead of `VARIABLE1`, `VARIABLE2`, I suppose because it feels like the digits blend into the words without an underscore separating them. For a more real example see `NUM2WORDS` v `NUM_2_WORDS`, the latter seems far clearer, at least to me.

Is this "wrong" (as far as the definition of that word can stretch)? What is the prevailing style and why?

Answer (score 0):

In prose (ordinary writing) you would write "variable 1" not "variable1", so for sake of consistency I think you should add an underscore when snake case is used, i.e. *variable_1*.

Comment: I suppose this is a fair point. Supporting this is the fact that in LaTeX one writes `x_1` not `x1` for the first version of variable `x`.